# push notifications IOS using FCM

Tags: php

I am using FCM to send push notification to IOS app, IOS dev provide me device token and SERVER_KEY, I search on google and tried different solutions but nothing worked for me , So let me know what is wrong with my code, Getting error {
  "multicast_id": 8569689262516537799,
  "success": 0,
  "failure": 1,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "error": "InvalidRegistration"
    }
  ]
}
**Thanks in advance**

```
    $ch = curl_init("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");

    //The device token.
    $token = "c2420d68a0838d8fb6b26ef06278e899de73a149e93c9fe13df11f70f3dd5cc1"; //token here
    //Title of the Notification.
    $title = "Carbon";

    //Body of the Notification.
    $body = "Bear island knows no king but the king in the north, whose name is stark.";

    //Creating the notification array.
    $notification = array('title' => $title, 'text' => $body);

    //This array contains, the token and the notification. The 'to' attribute stores the token.
    $arrayToSend = array('to' => $token, 'notification' => $notification, 'priority' => 'high');

    //Generating JSON encoded string form the above array.
    $json = json_encode($arrayToSend);
    //print_r($json); die();
    //Setup headers:
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: key=AAAAx6P1Nz0:APA91bEqkVCA9YRw9gpUvmF8UOVrYJ5T8672wfS_I7UAT3dA0g1QS7z-Z4fpn8JMiJ5kFRz9ZGc2K64hKZG-4__PAUqm733hqNDuFCDv9'; // key here
    //Setup curl, add headers and post parameters.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);


    //Send the request
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    //Close request
    print_r($response);
    curl_close($ch);

    //return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

token number ur sending is most probably wrong. try "/topics/all" this will send notification to all the users registered.